# VBA Updating and inserting only new data from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, updates

**EDIT TO BE MORE EXPLICIT:**

Imagine two Workbooks A and B. B is exported in .xlsx via an external program. It can't be modified.

1. In Week 1, I update Workbook A with data coming from Workbook B.

[Workbook A after Step 1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiVd8.jpg)

2. During Week 1, I work on Workbook A filling the Item column with data.

[Workbook A after Step 2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XySRq.jpg)

3. In Week 1, I update Workbook A with data coming from Workbook B again. But notice that some rows are not in the same position (row in green), others have suffered some modifications and some are just new.

[What I want to have in Workbook A after Step 3.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1y3gT.jpg)

Now I have this code:

```
Sub Update()

Dim lastRowScr As Integer, lastRowLocal As Integer, nRowsSrc As Integer, nRowsLocal As Integer, x As Integer, _
y As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
       Set closedBook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\mfortesg\Documents\Suivi d'Analyses AT\Projet - Automatisation\BO\BO.xlsx")
       
       lastRowScr = closedBook.Sheets(1).Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row - 2
       nRowsScr = lastRowScr - 16
       
       lastRowLocal = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tableau d'Analyse AT").Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
       nRowsLocal = lastRowLocal - 2
       
       If nRowsLocal = 0 Then
       
            For x = 17 To lastRowScr
            
                y = x - 14
                        
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tableau d'Analyse AT").Cells(y, 1).Value = closedBook.Sheets(1).Cells(x, 1).Value
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tableau d'Analyse AT").Cells(y, 2).Value = closedBook.Sheets(1).Cells(x, 2).Value
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tableau d'Analyse AT").Cells(y, 3).Value = closedBook.Sheets(1).Cells(x, 3).Value
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tableau d'Analyse AT").Cells(y, 4).Value = closedBook.Sheets(1).Cells(x, 4).Value
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tableau d'Analyse AT").Cells(y, 5).Value = closedBook.Sheets(1).Cells(x, 17).Value
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tableau d'Analyse AT").Cells(y, 6).Value = closedBook.Sheets(1).Cells(x, 11).Value
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tableau d'Analyse AT").Cells(y, 7).Value = closedBook.Sheets(1).Cells(x, 10).Value
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tableau d'Analyse AT").Cells(y, 8).Value = closedBook.Sheets(1).Cells(x, 26).Value
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tableau d'Analyse AT").Cells(y, 24).Value = Replace(closedBook.Sheets(1).Cells(x, 28).Value, ",", ":")
            
            Next x
            
            MsgBox ("Le Tableau d'Analyse AT a été mis à jour correctement.")
        
            Else
            
            For x = 17 To lastRowScr
    
                For y = x - 14 To lastRowLocal + 1
                    
                    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tableau d'Analyse AT").Cells(y, 1).Value = closedBook.Sheets(1).Cells(x, 1).Value And _
                       ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tableau d'Analyse AT").Cells(y, 2).Value = closedBook.Sheets(1).Cells(x, 2).Value And _
                       ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tableau d'Analyse AT").Cells(y, 24).Value = Replace(closedBook.Sheets(1).Cells(x, 28).Value, ",", ":") Then
                    
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tableau d'Analyse AT").Cells(y, 6).Value = closedBook.Sheets(1).Cells(x, 11).Value
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tableau d'Analyse AT").Cells(y, 5).Value = closedBook.Sheets(1).Cells(x, 17).Value
                        
                    ElseIf y = lastRowLocal + 1 Then
                                    
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tableau d'Analyse AT").Cells(x - 14, 1).Value = closedBook.Sheets(1).Cells(x, 1).Value
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tableau d'Analyse AT").Cells(x - 14, 2).Value = closedBook.Sheets(1).Cells(x, 2).Value
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tableau d'Analyse AT").Cells(x - 14, 3).Value = closedBook.Sheets(1).Cells(x, 3).Value
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tableau d'Analyse AT").Cells(x - 14, 4).Value = closedBook.Sheets(1).Cells(x, 4).Value
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tableau d'Analyse AT").Cells(x - 14, 5).Value = closedBook.Sheets(1).Cells(x, 17).Value
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tableau d'Analyse AT").Cells(x - 14, 6).Value = closedBook.Sheets(1).Cells(x, 11).Value
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tableau d'Analyse AT").Cells(x - 14, 7).Value = closedBook.Sheets(1).Cells(x, 10).Value
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tableau d'Analyse AT").Cells(x - 14, 8).Value = closedBook.Sheets(1).Cells(x, 26).Value
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tableau d'Analyse AT").Cells(x - 14, 24).Value = Replace(closedBook.Sheets(1).Cells(x, 28).Value, ",", ":")
                    
                    End If
                    
                Next y
            
            Next x
            
            MsgBox ("Le Tableau d'Analyse AT a été mis à jour correctement.")
        
        End If
            
       closedBook.Close SaveChanges:=False

     
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

It doesn't work as wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your external program can generate a unique id for each entry?
If yes, you can use it to verify new lines.

If not, I think that the best approach is using `concatenate` and `vlookup` to verify unique entries then insert new rows, like that:

In Workbook A, column E, use:

`=CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1)`

In Workbook C, column C, use:

`=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1),[Workbook A]Sheet1!C5,1,0),"NEW","DUPLICATE")`

Finally, in your code, you can verify if the cell value is "NEW" and insert them in Workbook A.

Comment: Thanks Pedro. The thing is Workbook C is a file exported by the external program. I don't want to do modifications on it. I want Workbook A to take only new data from Workbook C and insert it in the right row.

Comment: @Lorum in this case, you can create a temp file/sheet to do that modification.

Comment: Pedro, I edited my question so as to be clearer and more explicit. I also added the code I have at this moment.

Comment: Using you idea I finally create a column so as to have an ID to lookup.